# How to convert bytes byte by byte to signed int

Tags: python, python-3.x, signed

I have a `bytes` element. My word size is 1, a single byte. The contents can be `b'\xff\xff\x01'` meaning `[-1, -1, 1]`.

I want to convert it to the int representation from the bytes form.
Logically my attempt is:

```
ints = [int.from_bytes(j, byteorder='little', signed=True) for j in b'\xff\xff\x01']
```

> TypeError: cannot convert 'int' object to bytes

However this does not work as the `for j in bytes()` converts a bytes element directly into an int `j`. This is however an unsigned conversion, I need signed. How do I convert my bytes, byte by byte, into a signed integer.

Comment: "This is however an unsigned conversion, I need signed." Did you try doing the math to convert to 2s complement?

Comment: `bytes` *are* an array of ints, just presenting as sort-of ASCII string when printed as a whole.

Comment: @quamrana Does that *really* answer the question?

Comment: `ints = [int.from_bytes(bytes([j]), byteorder='little', signed=True) for j in b'\xff\xff\x01']`

Comment: @realSamy thanks, that also works. Really useless that such a hacky solution is needed to keep the correct type info

Comment: @KarlKnechtel this is python, why would I need to do bit twiddling when the `from_bytes` can do it.

Comment: @realSamy feel free to post your answer, I'll accept it as it is a better one than the hack I came up with

Comment: @deceze: Seems I was wrong. If only realSamy would post his answer.

Comment: "Really useless that such a hacky solution is needed to keep the correct type info" - Python 3.x correctly recognizes (aside from some very silly looking legacy methods like `zfill`) that bytes are **not text**. Python doesn't have a separate "character" type, so it makes sense for indexing into a string to give another string. Bytes are raw data; an individual byte does have a natural representation as the corresponding numeric value - which in Python is spelled `int`. Intuitively, indexing into a sequence that is "one-dimensional" ought to give a scalar value. 3.x fixes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, using Numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.frombuffer(b'\xff\xff\x01', dtype=np.int8)
array([-1, -1,  1], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: I switched to this solution over the approach I was using because of performance.

Answer (score 3):

> However this does not work as the `for j in bytes()` converts a bytes element directly into an int `j`.

As you've noticed, the `bytes` is already an iterable over integer values. If we have a lot of data, it would be more memory efficient to keep the `bytes` as is, and convert values on demand. We can simply do the math to convert the unsigned interpretation of a byte to the corresponding signed representation:

```
def signed_byte(b):
    return b - 256 if b >= 128 else b
```

And wrap the indexing process:

```
def get_signed(data, index):
    return signed_byte(data[index])
```

If we want or need to do all the conversion ahead of time, that feeds directly into the list comprehension:

```
ints = [signed_byte(b) for b in b'\xff\xff\x01']
```

On the other hand, we can reframe the question: to *get a `bytes` object from the original data as a subsequence* (like how it worked in 2.x), we can use a 1-element slice instead; or we can wrap the `int` value into a new `bytes`. The former will be tricky to adapt to the original code, but the latter is trivial:

```
ints = [int.from_bytes(bytes([b]), byteorder='little', signed=True) for b in b'\xff\xff\x01']
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is idiotic but at least it works.

```
data = b'\xff\xff\x01'
result = list(struct.unpack('b' * len(data), data))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it still helps! I saw your comment just now :)

```py
ints = [int.from_bytes(bytes([j]), byteorder='little', signed=True) for j in b'\xff\xff\x01']
```